# client_id and client_secret for MS translator integration with Omega T

Tags: azure, translate, clientid

I am trying to use MS translator with Omega T and the Omega T manual says to get the client_id and client_secret from the Azure console but I can only get keys.  I have looked online but the Azure console is updated from the time other tips were put up so I'm wondering if there are updated instructions.  I'll keep looking online but if anyone knows how to get these two pieces of info for pasting into Omega T as pointed to on their site here:  [Omega T site link](http://omegat.org/howtos/ms_translator)  please post them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the instructions are old.

Now its part of Microsoft cognitive services - please have a look on the links below:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/trial.aspx#get-started

-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account

To create Azure AD Client ID and Secret Key you can check this link: https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/creating-application-client-id-client-secret-microsoft-azure-new-portal/

I've done it for the FaceID but not for the translate service but it should be the same.

Comment: Hey I think I looked there already but I didn't see any references to client_id and client_secret.  It's in the right direction but I was hoping to find someone who had gone through the process themselves.

Comment: the client id and client secret is in my opinoin not the right direction here, as this has moved to the cognitive service, if you check the 2nd link, you will see there is Keys --> there is ur ID/Key.

Comment: before that, there was the option to create App in Azure AD and create Client ID and Secret Key: --> https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/creating-application-client-id-client-secret-microsoft-azure-new-portal/